# How to create structs with `New` prefix confusion

Tags: go, struct

I've been trying to get my head around some examples. 
I've seen code that creates structs with a simple `New` prefix (e.g. `NewSomething`), however, there is no function `NewSomething` defined which would do the actual `&Something{}` which I assumed was the necessary!?

For instance in this example [here](https://github.com/akiyosi/goneovim/blob/0de2036ca6660d54cacf4339115ab9622792ea99/editor/editor.go#L177), the function `NewEditorSignal` is called but I can't find the definition anywhere. When I try to do the same in my own code I'll get an

```
undefined: NewEditorSignal
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Two remarks: 1. Take the Tour of Go which explains basics about the language which 2. is called Go.

Comment: That function is probably generated. [The build instructions](https://github.com/akiyosi/goneovim/wiki/Development#build) show that the project isn't build with the standard Go tool chain (at least not directly), but something specific for Qt applications. The odd type definition for editorSignal is another hint for generated code.

Comment: Yes that was the problem! Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

`NewEditorSignal` does not have a package prefix, like `pkg.NewEditorSignal`, which means it is a symbol defined in the current package. If you want to call that function yourself from a different package, you have to import the package and call it with package prefix:

```
import (
   "github.com/akiyosi/goneovim/editor"
)

...
editor.NewEditorSignal()
```

Comment: I understand that if referenced from a different package than one would need the package name in front; searching in the repository I can't find the definition of NewEditorSignal anywhere, also not in the editor package?

Comment: Can you build the package?